# Extract file extension from URL path in R

Tags: regex, r, url, file-extension

I try to extract a file extension (if exists) from URLs like

```
> http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com&etc
> http://www.example.com/subpage1/subpage2/file.pdf
```

With `basename(URL)` function, I got the file. But when I was applying `sub()`, I get this

```
> sub(".*([.*])", "\\1", basename(URL))
> php?option=com&etc
> .pdf
```

How to retrieve only the extension (if exist)?

I have tried `file_ext(basename(URL))`. It works for the second example (when there is no parameter) but it gives nothing for the first.

```
file_ext(basename(URL))
[1] ""
```

Is it possible to have a regex that retrieve strings between "." and "?".

Comment: Please keep the offensive language out of your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of all the arguments listed after `?`, and then run `file_ext`:

```
tools::file_ext(sub("\\?.+", "", URL))
#[1] "php" "pdf"
```

Where `URL` was:

```
URL <- c(
"http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com&etc",
"http://www.example.com/subpage1/subpage2/file.pdf"
)
```